# multiple jQuery animate using chaining not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am learning jQuery and in the effects I saw a way called "chaining" and tried this code below but, to my shock, it's not animating the 2nd passed `animate()` method properly, i.e. the cube div is not moving from right to left.

I can't figure out what's wrong, except the 'right' part everything is working fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#anim").click(function() {

    $("#cube").animate({
      //here we give the parameters to change
      left: '150px', //move from left to right by 150px;
      opacity: '1',
      width: '100px',
      height: '100px'
    }, 3000).animate({
      right: "150px", //expected to move from right to left by 150px;
      opacity: '0.4',
      width: '50px',
      height: '50px'
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

```css
.cube {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  opacity: 0.4;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="anim">animate</button>
<div id="cube" class="cube">
  <p>cube</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: You should make it `left: "0px"` Not `right: "150px"`

Comment: Thankyou @ChinUdara Got it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `left` is the distance between the element and the left edge of the screen, and `right` is the distance between the element and the right edge of the screen.

Applying `right` after `left` does not move the element back to its original location - it's an entirely separate value.

To achieve what you require simply set `left` back to its original value. In this example, that's `8px`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#anim").click(function() {

    $("#cube").animate({
      left: '150px',
      opacity: 1,
      width: '100px',
      height: '100px'
    }, 3000).animate({
      left: '8px',
      opacity: 0.4,
      width: '50px',
      height: '50px'
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

```css
.cube {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  opacity: 0.4;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="anim">animate</button>
<div id="cube" class="cube">
  <p>cube</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help